# How to wait for routing to finish?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

When a user clicks on a link, it uses routing to send the user to another component, you start at home and can click to charts. My problem is that I need to get the queryselector for the charts element, but when code is loaded from the component, it  doesn't exist yet. How can I wait for the element to be created to execute the code?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a `MutationObserver` inside the constructor.

```
Element chartsElement;

ChartsComponent() {
  MutationObserver observer = MutationObserver(_onMutation);
  Element my_app = querySelector('my-app');
  observer.observe(my_app, childList: true);
}

_onMutation(List<dynamic> mutations, MutationObserver observer) {
  mutations.forEach((value) {
    MutationRecord record = value as MutationRecord;
    if (record.addedNodes.contains('charts')) {
      chartsElement = record.addedNodes[0];
    }
  });
  observer.disconnect();
  //Do stuff
}
```